# MySQL - Can I prevent a row from being SELECTed?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I have a table that has a lot of different queries going to it.

I want to add a feature that will allow me to essentially disable specified rows, so that they do not show up anywhere on the website.

Now, the obvious solution is to create a new column and add " `AND ACTIVE=TRUE`" to every `SELECT` query on the website. However, there are so many different `SELECT` queries, that it would be very unpractical to hunt down every single one. I would be bound to miss some.

Is there a more practical way to disable rows?

Comment: Write a filter around your Dao? Actually Drop the row and archive it somewhere?

Comment: Add your proposed column and create a `VIEW` to use instead of the table which applies that `ACTIVE=TRUE` condition.

Comment: I think your obvious solution is the best one.  As far as the volume of work goes, you should only have to do it once.

Comment: You could create a separate table for inactive rows, populate it, and then delete those rows from the original table

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Your solution is exactly what I needed. I just renamed the table to another name, and replaced it with a VIEW with the original name. Works like a charm! <3

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You should write up your solution as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Nikzilla Ok hang on.

Comment: @Nikzilla, if your php application has any pages that writes to the table in question, you just broke B by fixing A.

Comment: @DanBracuk Actually, you're wrong. It's updatable as long as the VIEW has the exact same collumns as it's source. More here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider creating a view which selects *all columns* from your table, but applies the condition `ACTIVE = TRUE` after you have created the `ACTIVE` column as you proposed in your question.  If you rename the original table and create the view with the table's former name, you may continue using it in your application seamlessly with the new limiting condition applied.

```
CREATE VIEW the_table_name AS (
  SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
  FROM the_renamed_table
  WHERE ACTIVE = TRUE
);
```

If performance doesn't seem to scale, you may need to add an index on the `ACTIVE` column.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in MySQL to set access on a row-level. You will have to do it in PHP. If you are using a database abstraction layer, such as Doctrine, there are ways to implement such functionality quickly. If all of your queries are written directly in the code, you are out of luck.